# How to fix delete button in laravel crud

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am trying to delete a record but when I press delete button it takes me to a white screen.
index.blade.php

```
<form>
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" formaction="{{ route('user.destroy',$user->id) }}">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Controller destroy function

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        User::findOrfail($user->id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('success','Record Deleted Successfully!!!');
    }
```

Route

```
Route::resource('/onemany/user',UserController::class);
```

[Route List for the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hziAw.png)
I am trying to delete the record. Tried using anchor tag also but getting same result with it.

Comment: There's no `action` attribute on the form element, no `name` attribute on the button. One of these is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the problem will occur at the route name and it wont enter the controller method at all.

You could do `php artisan route:list` and find out the correct route name.

Edit:

```
                           <form action="{{ route('user.destroy',$user->id) }}" method="Post">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: `DELETE          onemany/user/{user} .................................................. user.destroy › UserController@destroy` this is the route list for DELETE

Comment: Could you post it as a screenshot at the main post?

Comment: I added th elink for image of route list

Comment: @PranavSompura Edited the answer, it should work like that

Comment: Why would this work and `formaction` does not? Is it because there's no `method` in OPs code or something else?